# How Can I Load My Custom Font in imagestring()?

Tags: php, fonts, gd

My problem is Q title.

I tried http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php and: 
imageloadfont();

but i do not see any change and i get error:

```
Warning: imageloadfont(): gd warning: product of memory allocation multiplication would exceed INT_MAX, failing operation gracefully in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\texts\text01.php on line 3

Warning: imageloadfont(): Error reading font, invalid font header in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\texts\text01.php on line 3
```

Edit:
[My font](http://speedy.sh/CqCfg/btitr.TTF).

Comment: You can only load TrueType fonts using gd. Can you provide your font file? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your font is TrueType (.ttf) you should be using [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), not `imagestring()`. If you really do want to use `imagestring()` then your custom font does not match the font file format specification listed on the [`imageloadfont()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) manual page.

Comment: Look at to my edited please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256900/how-can-i-load-my-custom-font-in-imagestring#comment41192523_26256900), you should be using [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), not `imagestring()`.

Example usage, abbreviated/adapted from the manual page:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors and set background to white.
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'btitr.ttf';

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im, 'path_to_file.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: @sujitrulz That probably means an error has been generated but `display_errors` is off so you can't see it. Check the PHP error log.